# what is the limit of $\sum_{n>0}^\infty p^ncos(n\zeta)$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $p\in \mathbb{R}$  with $|p|<1$ and $\zeta \in \mathbb{R}$.

$\sum_{n>0}^\infty p^ncos(n\zeta)$ and $\sum_{n>0}^\infty p^nsen(n\zeta)$

I need to find the limit of this series, I need it for a theorem that I am proving, but I could not find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call these sums $C,\,S$ so$$1+C+iS=\sum_{n\ge0}(p\exp i\zeta)^n=\frac{1}{1-p\exp i\zeta}=\frac{1-p\cos\zeta+ip\sin\zeta}{1-2p\cos\zeta+p^2}.$$Hence$$C=\frac{p(\cos n\zeta-p)}{1-2p\cos n\zeta+p^2},\,S=\frac{p\sin\zeta}{1-2p\cos\zeta+p^2}.$$

Comment: what is $\exp in\zeta$

Comment: @jacques99 [$\exp ix=e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Euler's_formula). BTW I've edited my answer because now you're asking for two sums.